# Landing Zone Automation - Disable Owner requirement from ESLZ ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am trying to deploy ESLZ Arm template in this link "https://github.com/Azure/Enterprise-Scale/blob/main/docs/reference/adventureworks/README.md"  and it requires owner permission to do that. Is it possible to remove the Global Admin and/or Owner requirement  and run the template using contributor role

I created a management group under tenant root and assigned contributor role. Now I'm trying to create additional management groups using below ARM template

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/tenantDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "topLevelManagementGroupPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Provide prefix for the management group structure."
            }
        },
        "platformMgs": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                "management",
                "connectivity",
                "identity"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Management groups for platform specific purposes, such as management, networking, identity etc."
            }
        },
        "landingZoneMgs": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                "online",
                "corp"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "These are the landing zone management groups."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "enterpriseScaleManagementGroups": {
            "ESLZ": "[concat(parameters('topLevelManagementGroupPrefix'))]",
            "platform": "[concat(parameters('topLevelManagementGroupPrefix'), '-', 'platform')]"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            // Create management group for platform management groups
            "type": "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "scope": "/",
            "name": "[variables('enterpriseScaleManagementGroups').platform]",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "[variables('enterpriseScaleManagementGroups').platform]",
                "details": {
                    "parent": {
                    "id": "[tenantResourceId('Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/', parameters('topLevelManagementGroupPrefix'))]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

While deploying the template i'm getting permission error, however able to create management group manually. Am I missing something in this template. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Please note that the [tag:arm] tag is for the ARM CPU architecture, not for Azure Resource Manager which I guess is what this question is about.  I updated the tags but please double check.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to be able to deploy the template with contributor permissions at the tenant level...  You need an owner/userAccessAdmin/global admin to grant those permissions.